# How to save Polys of vtkPolyData to a database and assign them to vtkPoints?

Tags: python, c++, vtk

I want to save `vtkPolyData` to a database, to give me an idea How to do that I followed the example below (it creates some points, then exports them to a vtp file)

```
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkCellArray.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
#include <vtkXMLPolyDataWriter.h>
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
 
int main ( int, char *[] )
{
  // Create 10 points.
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
 
  for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
    {
    points->InsertNextPoint ( i, i, i );
    }
 
  // Create a polydata object and add the points to it.
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
  polydata->SetPoints(points);
 
  // Write the file
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter> writer =  
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLPolyDataWriter>::New();
  writer->SetFileName("test.vtp");
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
  writer->SetInput(polydata);
#else
  writer->SetInputData(polydata);
#endif
 
  // Optional - set the mode. The default is binary.
  //writer->SetDataModeToBinary();
  //writer->SetDataModeToAscii();
 
  writer->Write();
 
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now exporting data I am working on I realized, data is saved in the following fashion:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <VTKFile type="PolyData" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
      <PolyData>
        <Piece NumberOfPoints="290" NumberOfVerts="0" NumberOfLines="0" NumberOfStrips="0" NumberOfPolys="321">
          <PointData>
          </PointData>
          <CellData>
          </CellData>
          <Points>
            <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Points" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii" RangeMin="6796534.9032" RangeMax="6805936.2466">
              1520 1520 93.9992676 1567 1520 93.9992676
              1567 1612 93.9992676 1520 1612 93.9992676
              ...
            </DataArray>
         </Points>
        <Polys>
        <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" format="ascii" RangeMin="0" RangeMax="29031">
          0 1 2 3 1 4
          5 2 4 6 7 5
          6 8 9 7 8 10
          ...
 </DataArray>
      </Polys>
    </Piece>
  </PolyData>
</VTKFile>
```

So I thougt creating three tables

## Object

```
IdObject idPoints  idPolys 
1        1         1
```

then following table would have idPoints equal to 1 to relate it to #Object table

```
#Points
Id     X    Y    Z 
1      1520 1520 93.9992676 
2      1567 1520 93.9992676
3      1567 1612 93.9992676 
4      1520 1612 93.9992676
....
```

However I do not know how to store and even assign the polys to those points.
As far as I understand the polys give a geometry to the points connecting them right?

What would be the best way to store polys and also How to assign them to vtkPoints stored in a table?

```
#Polys
Id     ??????? 
1      0 1 2 3 1 4
       5 2 4 6 7 5
       6 8 9 7 8 10
....
```

Comment: Is there any restriction about the type of database, something like document based or noSQL could be a good alternative

Comment: no restriction at all, do you have some example or experience doing something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "assigning polys to vtkPoints". The Polys array represents polygons of the mesh, each of them being a vtkCell, which is basically just a set of points indices defining what points this polygon is made of and a npts - number of points this cell is made of. So you usually assign point indices to polys, not the other way around.

The point indices is what is stored in the connectivity array in your .vtu file. It should also be accompanied by an "offset" array describing where in the "connectivity" array starts an individual cell by defining offsets to that array. Theoretically it is not needed if your mesh is made of only one type of polys (e.g. only triangles), but in general that does not have to be true, so there should be an array like:

```
  <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" format="ascii" RangeMin="0" RangeMax="123456">
      3 6 10 13 ...
  </DataArray>
```

giving you first polygon with point indices 0 1 2, second with 3 1 4, third with 5 2 4 6 (a quad - can happen...), fourth with 7 5 6 etc.
Anyway, to use this kind of arrangement, your database would then look like:

```
#Polys
Id     pointIDList
0      0 1 2 
1      3 1 4
2      5 2 4 6
....
```

where the indices written in the pointIDList essentially point to your #Points table (assuming you change it to use zero-based indices ;) ). It is a reasonable arrangement, although I do not quite see what benefit you get over storing the vtu files...but I guess that is your concern.

If by "assigning polys to vtkPoints" you mean that you would like for each point to have a list of polys that are adjacent to it (that point is used to create that polygon), I would still use the #Polys database as desribed above and then added aditional table (or column to the #Points) with adjacency list, keeping indices of polys adjacent to the vertex. You can get that list from vtkPolyData by calling getPointCells(pointID, pointerToTheListToFill).